# Parallel lookup of a Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Is it possible for 2 or more processes to access a single Python dictionary or list? The processes perform read-only access, but they will at certain times simultaneously access the same element of the list/dict. I've tried the following using the standard library's [`concurrent.futures`](http://pythonhosted.org//futures/) module, but the execution time is terribly slow.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def f(x):
    return some_dictionary[x]

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    results = executor.map(f, some_list)
```

Comment: Because if you use ProcessPoolExecutor, all your result needs to pickle from worker process to result queue and unpickle it.